# Change in MS .cfg script

Tags: outlook

I have found an article on the HowTo-Outlook website (by Robert Sparnaaij) with instructions for how to show the sender's e-mail address as a column in Outlook's message view.  I would like to do almost the same thing, but showing the *recipient* e-mail address in its own column.  Can anyone advise how to edit Robert's viewsenderaddress.cfg file (downloaded from http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/viewsenderaddress.htm) to work for the recipient, rather than sender, address?  Thanks in advance.

NB - This is the cfg file as it stands:

```
DesignerRuntimeGuid={0006F020-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
CLSID={00020D31-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
DisplayName=Sender's Email Address
Category=Standard
Subcategory=Form
Comment=This form is used to expose the sender's email address in a View.
LargeIcon=IPML.ico
SmallIcon=IPMS.ico
Version=1.0
VersionMajor=1
VersionMinor=0
Locale=enu
Hidden=1
Owner=www.howto-outlook.com
ComposeInFolder=1

[Platforms]
Platform2=NTx86
Platform9=Win95

[Platform.NTx86]
CPU=ix86
OSVersion=WinNT3.5

[Platform.Win95]
CPU=ix86
OSVersion=Win95

[Properties]
Property01=SenderEmailAddress
[Property.SenderEmailAddress]
Type=30
NmidInteger=0x0c1f
DisplayName=From E-mail Address

[Verbs]
Verb1=1

[Verb.1]
DisplayName=&Open
Code=0
Flags=0
Attribs=2

[Extensions]
Extensions1=1

[Extension.1]
Type=30
NmidPropset={00020D0C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
NmidInteger=1
Value=1000000000000000
```